# Solution wide app.config / web.config?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with one asp.net-mvc-2 project, one web service, one class library and three normal desktop apps. Currently I need to copy all app.config settings from one project to the other. That is a nightmare if I want to change something.

I know there is a solution to store all these information in the global .config files, but I am looking for a solution to store the values dedicated to my solution not to my machine. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a single .config file to one of your projects, and then choose ***Add -> Existing Item... -> Add As Link*** to add a reference to that file to your other projects. They will all build with the file as if it was their own copy, but there will really only be one copy, and you will only have to make changes in a single place.

Comment: I can confirm: RhysO's approach works great. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community with C# .Net 4.6.1. with console and class libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a really simple solution [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/03/05/dry-shared-web-config-settings/):

**1. Create a file `CommonSettings.config` In your Common, Class library project.**

**2. Put your common setting in this file:**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="someCommonSetting" value="some value"></add>
    <!-- more setting here -->
</appSettings>
```

Note: `<appSetting>` has to be the root element in your `CommonSettings.config` (don't put it under `<configuration>`)

**3. Make sure `CommonSettings.config` file is copied to output directory:**

[image]

**4. In all other project's App.Config/Web.config files, add the above common settings**

That's it... You common settings will be included in every other config file.

```
<appSettings file="CommonSettings.config">
    <add key="Value1" value="123" />
</appSettings>
```

**Note:**

> For this approach to work, the shared config file should be copied to
>   the project’s output directory so it is adjacent to the regular
>   App/Web.config file. Add the existing shared .config file to the
>   project as a Linked file and set it to ‘Copy if newer’. You should see
>   something similar to this in your .csproj file:
>
> ```
> <None Include="..\CommonConnectionStrings.config">
>   <Link>CommonConnectionStrings.config</Link>
>   <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
> </None>
> ```

---

You can do the same for `ConnectionString`, copy all your connection strings in `CommonConnectionStrings.config`, and in other App.Config/Web.Config, reference it like this:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="CommonConnectionStrings.config" />
```

Note: If you are using this solution for `connectionStrings`, you cannot have a project specific connection string, all of the connection strings will be copied from the common config.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you could have a path where both your website and webservice could access it, then you could potentially use the appsettings " file " attribute to have the settings stored in one common place.
Refer http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/appsettings_fileattribute.aspx
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would comment on the answer [@Sahuagin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11265690/2350083) gave, but I don't have enough reputation. This does work with App.config files, but you have to add a text file, then call it App.config. After that just declare the XML (as seen below)

```
<configuration>
   <!-- add you values or whatever here-->
</configuration>
```

Then do as [@Sahuagin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11265690/2350083) said and add it as a link to your solution. It works a treat.